# the site on iis is not accessible from the global network

Tags: asp.net-core, iis

I hosted my ASP.NET Core on an IIS server, in principle everything is fine, from the local network it is accessible by ip and port (192.168.1.15:6100), the problem is that it is not accessible from the global network, the ip is static, for example:

(79.190.11.241:6100)

- Windows Server 2012 r2
- IIS 8.0

The ports on the modem are forwarded. Just for fun, I installed Apache 2.4 on port 85, and everything worked fine from the global network.

Comment: Then enjoy your own adventure. People rarely discuss end of life products or home networking setup here, as that’s not worth the while or directly linked to programming.

Answer (score 0):

I have also used IIS to host my web server cause it is convenient to do so. I simply publish the application to a local folder and set the website physical path to that folder. Maybe you can have a check on these issues:

1. open the port in the firewall
2. set the port and other properties in the IIS
3. create the DNS records in domain hosting service

Answer (score 0):

According to your description, the problem may lie in the firewall or network settings. You can check the following settings for troubleshooting:

1. Check the server's firewall settings to make sure port 6100 is allowed to be accessed from the internet. You may need to add outbound rules in your firewall.
2. Check the router settings to ensure that port forwarding is configured correctly on the router to forward external access port 6100 to port 6100 of the server's internal IP address 192.168.1.15.
3. In the startup settings of your ASP.NET Core application, make sure it is listening on the correct IP address and port. You may want to change this to 0.0.0.0:6100 to listen on all available IP addresses, not just the local network.
4. Check the logs on the server to see if there are any error or warning messages about access issues.